# HTML5 CSS3 nested DIV positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

```
/* HTML */
<header role="heading">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="/">this is the banner</a></h1>
    </div>
<header>

/* CSS */
header
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
}

header .logo
{
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 980px;
}
```

So, I would expect for `.logo` to center inside of `header`, and it does... but it pulls `header` 30px from the top.

I have tried making `header` relative but that only causes the centering (30px auto) not to work.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset? H1 has its own padding/margin by default.

Comment: Yes. The H1 is sized and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the margin effects the parent as well, I recommend the following approach: Keep your markup the same and use padding on the container instead of margin on the child element.

```
/* CSS */
header
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    padding:30px 0px; /* Use padding here*/
}

header .logo
{
    margin: 0px auto; /* Instead of margin here */
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely! That was what I discovered after I looked at it for a second... Sometimes it take asking the question out loud to get the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of embarrassing, but I looked at the question once I posted it and saw the answer...
I used `margin: 0 auto` to center `.logo` and `padding-top: 30px` to bring it down.

Sorry to waste time! Maybe that will help someone else.